# Android MediaPlayer is paused, volume buttons do not control multimedia

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-developer-api

I played a sample music (.mp3) using a sample code I found on the Internet.
The code is something like

```
MediaPlayer mp = new ...
mp.setDataSource(...
mp.setAudioStreamType(...
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

The problem is that when the music is paused, the volume buttons do not control multimedia volume but notification volume.

```
mp.pause();
```

This behaviour is different from other music players I have tested. Samsung's built-in Music, VLC, and other programs still showed multimedia volume when the music has been paused.

How can I make multimedia volume appear when music is paused?

PS: It seems other players make pressing volume buttons control multimedia volume, no matter what the current playing status is, even playing has not been started at all. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by putting the following code in my onCreate() function.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```